# JQuery Passing Variables on Button Click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am using JQueryUI Dialog box to show a link. I have 20 buttons with 20 different links. I wan't to pass that link so the Dialog box knows which link to open.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                var id = $(this).data('aid'); // It does not work here
                $(this).load("Link?id=" + id);
            },
            hide:
            {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 500
            }
        });
    });

    $('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data('aid'); // Works here. I wan't to pass this.
        $("#dialog").dialog("open")
    });
});
```

MVC/Razor:

```
<input type="submit" value="Show" class="button" data-aid="@Model.item.id" />
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to opening the dialog, set a data property to `#dialog` - which is inturn accessible as `this` inside the `open()` callback:

```
$("#dialog").data('aid', $(this).data('aid')).dialog("open");
```

Now this should work:

```
...
open: function (event, ui) {
    var id = $(this).data('aid'); // Now it will work here
    $(this).load("Link?id=" + id);
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect. I still hate JavaScript. ):